# How to use Webview's Identifier which's set in IB's Attribute inspector?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

Here is a screenshot from the attribute inspector:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do you know what it’s for but you don’t know how to use it?

Comment: Yes. I want to use the webview in my window. I found -(id)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)aTag, but I can't set tag on my webview in IB. Just think that the Identifier might help but I don't know what it's for and how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifier field in Interface Builder is equivalent to `-[WebView setPreferencesIdentifier:]`. This identifier is stored in the defaults database and refers to a set of preferences that can be shared amongst different `WebView` objects. From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WebView/setPreferencesIdentifier:):

> The unique identifier for the preferences—it is fixed to the keys used to store the receiver’s preferences in the user defaults database. `WebView` objects can share instances of the `WebPreferences` class by using the same preferences identifier.
>
> This method sets the receiver’s preferences to the specified preferences object if it exists. Otherwise, this method creates a new `WebPreferences` object for the receiver initialized with anIdentifier. Use this method to change the preferences used by the receiver’s `WebFrameView` objects. If you do not directly set the preferences, `WebFrameView` objects use the preferences returned by the `standardPreferences` class method of `WebPreferences`.

If you want to reference a `WebView` object in code, the most common options are setting an `IBOutlet` or using `tag`.